# Is there a way to bulk-add ElasticSearch percolations?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I want to throw my many documents to a LOT of percolator queries (my query count is in the 6-digit). I've found how to multi-percolate many documents at once, but haven't found how to bulk-add many queries at once.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html), I can register a query in the percolator using:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "bonsai tree"
        }
    }
}'
```

Can I add many of these in one fell swoop?

Comment: I think the "bulk" percolate operations IS the multi-percolate: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2336

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andrei. You are right in saying that bulk percolate is multi percolate, but 'to percolate' is to send many documents to the percolators (aka the stored queries). I'm looking to add many percolators (those queries). https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since queries are indexed like normal documents would, you could simply bulk-add them like this:

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk -d '
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index", "_type" : ".percolator", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "query" : { "match" : { "message" : "bonsai tree" } }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index", "_type" : ".percolator", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "query" : { "match" : { "message" : "abc" } }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index", "_type" : ".percolator", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "query" : { "match" : { "message" : "def" } }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my-index", "_type" : ".percolator", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "query" : { "match" : { "message" : "xyz" } }}
'
```